# Looping through PuLP nested variables for specific constraints

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, pulp, operations-research

I have the following constraint:

`sum of (between p = 0 to p = 2) of X_sap <= A_sa`

**My classes are:**

```
# s
site_classes = [1, 2]
# a
age_classes = [1, 2, 3]
# p
period_classes = [0, 1, 2]

age_areas = {1: {'age_range': '0to10', 1: 3000, 2: 8000},
             2: {'age_range': '11to20', 1: 6000, 2: 4000},
             3: {'age_range': '21to30', 1: 9000, 2: 7000}}
```

**My sap is defined as follow:**

```
sap = []
for s in site_classes:
    for a in age_classes:
        for p in period_classes:
            sap.append(f'{s}_{a}_{p}')
```

**Here's how I'm creating my X_sap:**

`x_vars = lp.LpVariable.dicts("X", sap, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')`

**Here's how I'm creating my area constraints**

```
area_c_dict = {}
for s in site_classes:
    for a in age_classes:
        for p in period_classes:
            area_c_dict[f'{s}_{a}_{p}'] = age_areas[a][s]
```

**I'm struggling to generate my constraints to output in this way**

```
X110 + X111 + X112 <= 3,000
X120 + X121 + X122 <= 6,000
X130 + X131 + X132 <= 9,000
X210 + X211 + X212 <= 8,000
X220 + X221 + X222 <= 4,000
X230 + X231 + X232 <= 7,000
```

**My outputted variables are**

```
area_c_dict = {'1_1_0': 3000, '1_1_1': 3000, '1_1_2': 3000, '1_2_0': 6000, '1_2_1': 6000, '1_2_2': 6000, '1_3_0': 9000, '1_3_1': 9000, '1_3_2': 9000, '2_1_0': 8000, '2_1_1': 8000, '2_1_2': 8000, '2_2_0': 4000, '2_2_1': 4000, '2_2_2': 4000, '2_3_0': 7000, '2_3_1': 7000, '2_3_2': 7000}


x_vars = {'1_1_0': X_1_1_0, '1_1_1': X_1_1_1, '1_1_2': X_1_1_2, '1_2_0': X_1_2_0, '1_2_1': X_1_2_1, '1_2_2': X_1_2_2, '1_3_0': X_1_3_0, '1_3_1': X_1_3_1, '1_3_2': X_1_3_2, '2_1_0': X_2_1_0, '2_1_1': X_2_1_1, '2_1_2': X_2_1_2, '2_2_0': X_2_2_0, '2_2_1': X_2_2_1, '2_2_2': X_2_2_2, '2_3_0': X_2_3_0, '2_3_1': X_2_3_1, '2_3_2': X_2_3_2}
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated on how I can achieve that. I'm not sure how to loop through my x_vars without breaking it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your decision variables like this:

```
x_vars = lp.LpVariable.dicts("X", [(s,a,p) for s in site_classes for a in age_classes for p in period_classes] , lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
```

Then use the `lpSum` function from the pulp library to make your constraints:

```
for s in site_classes:
    for a in age_classes:
        prob += lp.lpSum(x_vars[(s,a,p)] for p in period_classes) <= age_areas[a][s]
```

The `prob` variable is an instance of the `LpProblem` class

---

*Demonstration on how to define a decision variable for the sum of variables to be used in other constraints*

define a free variable

```
sum_var = lp.LpVariable.dicts("sum_of_variables", [(s,a) for s in site_classes for a in age_classes] , cat='Continuous')
```

now add a definition to your free variable.

```
for s in site_classes:
    for a in age_classes:
        prob += lp.lpSum(x_vars[(s,a,p)] for p in period_classes) == sum_var[(s,a)]
```

Now you can use your free variable in a constraint

```
for s in site_classes:
    for a in age_classes:
        prob += sum_var[(s,a)] <= age_areas[a][s]
```

This approach can improve the readability of you linear program and makes it easier to add complexity to the model

Comment: Thanks, this was great. On another question, is it possible to define a "sum of variables" as a constraint variable to be used multiple times in constraints if that makes any sense?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Simply define a decision variable for the sum of variables and use the variable in your constriant. i'll make an edit in the answer to demonstrate

Comment: i hope this was the answer you were looking for

Comment: Actually, it's better if you just do `sum_var[(s,a)] = lp.lpSum(x_vars[(s,a,p)] for p in period_classes)` instead of `prob += lp.lpSum(x_vars[(s,a,p)] for p in period_classes) == sum_var[(s,a)]`. No need to add the constraint, by filling the variable `sum_var` with a pulp expression you can use it whenever a variable would be used and you use less constraints.